# why django is not adding user to my table (i'm using postgres)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i'm trying to add users to user table which comes default by django,
but unfortunately it is not adding the users to table after submitting the register form .

whenever i'm submiting the form it is not adding user to the table , even when i'm trying to print on console it is also not working :( don't know what to do , please help me

this is my settings.py

```
   DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': 'telusko',
            'USER':'postgres',
            'PASSWORD':'root',
            'HOST':'localhost'
        }
    }
```

this is my register.html

```
  <Html>
<head> 
<title>
Registration Page
</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="Lightskyblue">
<br>

<form action="/users/register" method="post" >
 {% csrf_token %}

<label> Firstname </label>       
<input type="text" name="firstname" size="15"/> <br> <br>

<label> Lasttname </label>       
<input type="text" name="laststname" size="15"/> <br> <br>


<label> username </label>       
<input type="text" name="username" size="15"/> <br> <br>

<label> Password: </label>   
<input type="password" name="password2" size="15"/> <br> <br>

<label> Conform Password: </label> 
<input type="password" name="password2" size="15"/> <br> <br>

<label> Email: </label>
<input type="email" name="email" size="15"/> <br> <br>
      
  
 <input type="submit" value="  Register  " size="15"/> <br> 

</form>
```

this is my views.py for register app

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        print("success")
        first_name= request.POST['firstname']
        last_name= request.POST['lastname']
        username=request.POST['username']
        password1= request.POST['password1']
        password2= request.POST['password2']
        email=request.POST['email']
        if password1==password2:
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "USER NAME TAKEN ")
            else:
                user=User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password1,email=email,
                first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name)
                user.save()
                messages.SUCCESS(request, messages.INFO, "SUCCESS HOMIE ")
    else:
        return render(request,'register.html')
```

[databse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYaF8.png)

Answer (score 1):

TO all i got the answer problem lies in my html, the thing is i'm creating template
folder for each app so for form when i'm setting action = "register/register" it won't work even though my views and url.py are correct becoz i'm creating template subfolder inside my app so django will not know it so the only solution is to use
{% url 'register' %}"  note u must set ur app url with name , in my case my app is register so i set it's name as register

```
  from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/',views.register,name="register")
]
```

before adding url

```
 <form action="register/register" method="post" >
 {% csrf_token %}

<label> Firstname </label>       
<input type="text" name="firstname" size="15"/> <br> <br>

<label> Lasttname </label>       
<input type="text" name="lastname" size="15"/> <br> <br>


<label> username </label>       
<input type="text" name="username" size="15"/> <br> <br>

<label> Password: </label>   
<input type="password" name="password1" size="15"/> <br> <br>

<label> Conform Password: </label> 
<input type="password" name="password2" size="15"/> <br> <br>

<label> Email: </label>
<input type="email" name="email" size="15"/> <br> <br>
      
  
 <input type="submit" value="  Register  " size="15"/> <br> 

</form>
```

after adding url

```
 <form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="post" >
 {% csrf_token %}

<label> Firstname </label>       
<input type="text" name="firstname" size="15"/> <br> <br>

<label> Lasttname </label>       
<input type="text" name="lastname" size="15"/> <br> <br>


<label> username </label>       
<input type="text" name="username" size="15"/> <br> <br>

<label> Password: </label>   
<input type="password" name="password1" size="15"/> <br> <br>

<label> Conform Password: </label> 
<input type="password" name="password2" size="15"/> <br> <br>

<label> Email: </label>
<input type="email" name="email" size="15"/> <br> <br>
      
  
 <input type="submit" value="  Register  " size="15"/> <br> 

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `password2` duplicated two times in the HTML. Is it just a typo in the post or do you have the same typo in your code?
Does your `urls.py` point to this view?
Also, you should use a debugger in such cases.

Just put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` on the first line of your view, then your code will pause on that line. You will be able to execute the code line by line by pressing `n`. Check the debugger docs, it's an essential tool docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: in my views.py as u can see above code , there no typo error there, it should work becoz they both will be same eventhough in html if i had a typo

Comment: i got the solution , the problem lies in action , i should use url becoz i'm creating template folder inside my app, so django will not know path until and unless i use {% url 'register' %}"